# TypeError: require(...) is not a function nodejs

Tags: node.js

Olá alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Tenho um server backend em nodejs

no index.js tenho a importacao de todos os controller  porem tomo um erro TypeError: require(...) is not a function quando ler meu arquivo que faze a junção de todos os controllers da pasta.

Meus index

```
const express         = require('express');
const bodyParser      = require('body-parser'); 
const cors            = require('cors');
const fs              = require('fs');

const app             =  express();
const port            = 3010;


//  const intergracaoLogs = require('./routes/remessa-route')
// const controllers = require('./app/Controllers/rem')

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extends:false,limit: '50mb'} ));



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // console.log('request', req.url, req.body, req.method);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-token");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.end();
  } else {
      next();
  }
});



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-token");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.end();
  } else {
      next();
  }
});


require('./app/Controllers/index')(app)

//  app.use(intergracaoLogs)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`SERVER RUNNING app on port ${port} `)
  })
```

meu  index da pasta do controle que vai pegar todos arquivos da pasta.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = (app) => {
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file) => file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== "index.js")
    .forEach((file) => require(path.join(__dirname, file))(app));
};
```

tentei solucionar sem sucesso